# FeathersJS: post-process service

Tags: feathersjs

Using feathersJs, I have a service which deliver a JSON on this format :

```
{"results": [{
  "columns":["n"],
   "data": [
     {"row": [{"name":"Tom","alias":"Tommy"}]},
     {"row": [{"name":"John"},"alias":"Johnny"}]}
   ]}
 ]}
```

And I would like to know if it is possible to apply some process (hooks ?) in order to obtain an Array as for example :

```
[
     {"row": [{"name":"Tom","alias":"Tommy"}]},
     {"row": [{"name":"John"},"alias":"Johnny"}]}
   ]
```

In a general, is it possible to post-treat a Promise return in feathers ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `after` hook like:

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) { 
  return context => {
    // work on context.result and change it
    return context
  }
}
```

Feel free to change the result like you want within it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alinex !
I just handled it today, by implementing a function inside hook, but I couldn't understand before, now I see.

I have to say feathers is great as "close" as I know from it